# How can I convert u32 datatype to bigInt in Rust?

Tags: rust, type-conversion, fibonacci

I am doing Fibonacci sequence function and the return type should return BigUint type. I search through many webs but I couldn't find the site that show the way.
This is my process so far.

```
pub fn fibo_seq(n: u32) -> Vec<num_bigint::BigUint> {
    let mut f1 = 0;
    let mut temp = 1;
    let mut f2 = 1;
    let mut vec:Vec<u32> = Vec::new();

    while vec.len() < n.try_into().unwrap(){
       vec.push(f2);
       temp = f2;
       f2 = f1 + f2;
       f1 = temp;  

    }

    vec // return wrong data type

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't just put `BigUint` in the return type, you have to actually use it!

```
pub fn fibo_seq(n: u32) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    let mut f1 = BigUint::from(0u32);
    let mut temp = BigUint::from(1u32);
    let mut f2 = BigUint::from(1u32);
    let mut vec: Vec<BigUint> = Vec::new();

    while vec.len() < n.try_into().unwrap(){
       vec.push(f2.clone());
       temp = f2.clone();
       f2 = f1 + &f2;
       f1 = temp;  

    }

    vec
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are return `Vec<BigUint>` you need `Vec<BigUint>` instead of `Vec<u32>`.

To improve you can rewrite the same method without temp variable as below.

```rs
use num_bigint::BigUint;

pub fn fibo_seq(n: u32) -> Vec<BigUint> {
    let mut f1 = BigUint::from(0u32);
    let mut f2 = BigUint::from(1u32);
    let mut vec:Vec<BigUint> = Vec::new();

    while vec.len() < n.try_into().unwrap() {
       (f2, f1) = (f1 + &f2, f2);
       vec.push(f1.clone());
    }

    vec
}
```

Comment: It seems a bit pointless to use `u32` in the calculation and only convert to `BigUint` as the last step. Your code overflows with quite small values (`fibo_seq(47)`), which is presumably why OP was using `BigUint` in the first place.